# Getting matplotlib figure axes type

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot, scatter

I wanted to plot a scatter from a csv data file (refer below).

[image]

I have already define for the plot and it already print the graph that I wanted.

```
def plot_calibration_curve(calib_data):
    plot = calib_data.plot(kind='scatter', x="conc X", y="Abs")
    plot.set_xlabel("$\mathrm{[X]\ /\ mol\ dm}^{-3}$")
    plot.set_ylabel('Absorbance')

plot_calibration_curve(calibration_data_X)
```

Plot output:

[image]

But when I ran this test, it gives a blank error;

```
assert isinstance(plot_calibration_curve(calibration_data_X), matplotlib.figure.Axes)
Output= AssertionError:
```

How do I get the matplotlib.figure.Axes type for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function

```
def plot_calibration_curve(calib_data):
    plot = calib_data.plot(kind='scatter', x="conc X", y="Abs")
    plot.set_xlabel("$\mathrm{[X]\ /\ mol\ dm}^{-3}$")
    plot.set_ylabel('Absorbance')
```

just plots, doesn't return anything. That is, it returns `None`. You will get `True` if you do

```
plot_calibration_curve(calib_data) is None
```

You want to try:

```
def plot_calibration_curve(calib_data):
    plot = calib_data.plot(kind='scatter', x="conc X", y="Abs")
    plot.set_xlabel("$\mathrm{[X]\ /\ mol\ dm}^{-3}$")
    plot.set_ylabel('Absorbance')

    # return
    return plot
```

Comment: omg, thank you! it works! i have tried return plt.show() before, but it still gives error.